# Is there a way to not display my model in the template?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to know if it is possible not to show/load my Product model when viewing a template. Instead, I want to display my model on click a button that filters the results before displaying them.

I have more than 30,000 records in my Product model and that is why I don't want them to show/load when viewing my template, I know that the paginate_by = '100' method exists, but I find it more useful to filter the records before displaying them

Note: I already have the function and class to filter my Product model records

```
class barcodeview(ListView):
    template_name = "barcode/table.html"
    paginate_by = '500'
    model= Product
    context_object_name = 'product'
    
    # Queryset for filtering product model
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.barcode_filter(
            filtr = self.request.GET.get("filtr", ''),
        )

        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your filter form in your template and only output models when the form is submitted.

Template:

```
<form method="get">
  <input ...>
  <button type="submit" name="filter">Filter</button>
</form>
```

view:

```
class BarCodeView(ListViw):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if 'filter' not in self.request.GET:
            return self.model.objects.none()

        filter_form = FilterForm(self.queryset.GET)
        if not filter_form.is_valid():
            return self.model.objects.none()

        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if filter_form.cleaned_data['some_filter_field']:
             qs = qs.filter(some_field=filter_form.cleaned_data['some_filter_field']
         
         # more filters if your need
         ...

         return qs
```

You can adapt this to your needs. The filtering can also be done on the form:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
     some_filter_field = forms.ChoieField(...)

     def filter(self, qs):
         """Method added to the original django form, you
         will not find it in the documentation"""
         if self.cleaned_data['some_filter_field']:
             qs = qs.filter(....)

         return qs

class BarCodeView(ListView):
     def get_queryset(self):
         if 'filter' in self.request.GET:
              return self.model.none()

         form = FilterForm(self.request.GET)
         if form.is_valid():
             return form.filter(self.model.objects.all())

         return self.model.none()
```

Those aren't the only ways of doing it, but you got the point.